# Entity Framework many to many retrieval data with LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

I have two tables `AspNetUsers` and `AspNetRoles` with many to many dependence in table `AspNetUserRoles`. I want to display any user with his role ( if role is null i want to display that ).

In SQL query is:

```
SELECT u.Email, u.FirstName, u.LastName, r.Name as 'Role'
FROM AspNetUserRoles as ur
 RIGHT JOIN AspNetUsers as u
  ON ur.UserId = u.Id
 LEFT JOIN AspNetRoles as r
  ON ur.RoleId = r.Id
```

I want to transform it into LINQ query. I write query for my `AspNetUserRoles` table and retriev data, but result display only if have user with role.

```
IQueryable<RoleViewModel> result = from user in context.AspNetUsers
                                           from r in user.AspNetRoles
                                           select new RoleViewModel{
                                               Email = user.Email,
                                               FirstName = user.FirstName,
                                               LastName = user.LastName,
                                               Role = r.Name
                                           };
```

Can you help me?

**EDIT**

That is work:

```
IQueryable<RoleViewModel> result = from user in context.AspNetUsers
                                           from r in user.AspNetRoles.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                           select new RoleViewModel{
                                               Email = user.Email,
                                               FirstName = user.FirstName,
                                               LastName = user.LastName,
                                               Role = r != null ? r.Name : null
                                           };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DefaultIfEmtpy` method to join with linq:

```
var result = from user in context.UserEntities
from r in user.RoleEntities.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
    Email = user.Email,
    FirstName = user.FirstName,
    LastName = user.LastName,
    Role = r != null ? r.RoleName : null
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I write a query `from r in user.AspNetRoles into temp`  throw error: "Type inference faild in the call to 'SelectMany'".